# how to restrict html table row height in WebGrid

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

html table one column contains lot of text and table looks ugly, there is too much space between rows.
How to make table better so that there is not so much space, long column should be wider and maybe some of content not visible?

I tried to use max-height , but it is ignored.
Table is generated automatically by ASP.NET MVC4 WebGrid from dynamic data. how to force WebGrid to 
render without large spaces between rows ?

view:

```
@inherits ViewBase<Eeva.Erp.ViewModels.ReportDataViewModel>
@using System.Web.Helpers

@{ Layout = null;
 var gd = new WebGrid(source: Model.Rows, canSort: false);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    tr {
     max-height :50px;

    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  @gd.GetHtml()
</body>
</html>
```

viewmodel:

```
public class ReportDataViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
        public IEnumerable<dynamic> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">

    tr {
     max-height :50px;

    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
      <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
calculrow            </th>
            <th scope="col">
doktyyp            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokumnr            </th>
            <th scope="col">
fifoexpens            </th>
            <th scope="col">
hind            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klass            </th>
            <th scope="col">
kogpak            </th>
            <th scope="col">
kogus            </th>
            <th scope="col">
koopia            </th>
            <th scope="col">
nimetus            </th>
            <th scope="col">
paritoluri            </th>
            <th scope="col">
prepayment            </th>
            <th scope="col">
toode            </th>
            <th scope="col">
vat            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokarvekonto            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokeimuuda            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokkrdokumnr            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokkuupaev            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokraha            </th>
            <th scope="col">
doksaaja            </th>
            <th scope="col">
doktasudok            </th>
            <th scope="col">
doktasukuup            </th>
            <th scope="col">
doktekst1            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientaadress            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientnimi            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientotsekorral            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientpiirkond            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientpostiindek            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klienttanav            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientviitenr            </th>
            <th scope="col">
kreeditdoktasudok            </th>
            <th scope="col">
maksetintingimus            </th>
            <th scope="col">
myygikookmprotsent            </th>
            <th scope="col">
myygikoomaksuvaba            </th>
            <th scope="col">
saajanimi            </th>
            <th scope="col">
saajapiirkond            </th>
            <th scope="col">
saajapostiindek            </th>
            <th scope="col">
saajatanav            </th>
            <th scope="col">
toodekaubakood            </th>
            <th scope="col">
toodeklass            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>2045</td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>362,28813</td>
            <td>T</td>
            <td>0,0000</td>
            <td>2,0000</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Siduri- ja piduriheebel kinnitustega              </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>32-30100            </td>
            <td>1775,61</td>
            <td>112       </td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>27.11.2013 0:00:00</td>
            <td>EUR</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>359                      </td>
            <td>7.12.2013 0:00:00</td>
            <td>Arve 988 26.01.2012
Arve  16.08.2012
Arve 290 16.08.2012
Muu sissetulnud 24
Muu sissetulnud 25 2
Kassa sissetulek 8 4
Tellimus 43 05.01.2012
Tellimus 46 24.12.2011
Arve 292 10.01.2013
V&#228;ljastus 17.05.2013
Arve 344 27.09.2013
Arve 344 27.09.2013
Arve 05.11.2013
Tellimus 47 09.08.2013
Arve 20.12.2013</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Acura UAB                                                                       </td>
            <td>767       </td>
            <td>                              </td>
            <td>          </td>
            <td>Huan Uh 2                                                   </td>
            <td>23445456            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>10 p&#228;eva, viivis 0.5% p&#228;evas                      </td>
            <td>20,00</td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>Acura UAB                                                                       </td>
            <td>                              </td>
            <td>          </td>
            <td>Huan Uh 2                                                   </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>2045</td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>0,43700</td>
            <td>T</td>
            <td>0,0000</td>
            <td>0,0000</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Balti v&#252;rtsikilud 270g                            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0075                </td>
            <td>1775,61</td>
            <td>112       </td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>27.11.2013 0:00:00</td>
            <td>EUR</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>359                      </td>
            <td>7.12.2013 0:00:00</td>
            <td>Arve 988 26.01.2012
Arve  16.08.2012
Arve 290 16.08.2012
Muu sissetulnud 24
Muu sissetulnud 25 2
Kassa sissetulek 8 4
Tellimus 43 05.01.2012
Tellimus 46 24.12.2011
Arve 292 10.01.2013
V&#228;ljastus 17.05.2013
Arve 344 27.09.2013
Arve 344 27.09.2013
Arve 05.11.2013
Tellimus 47 09.08.2013
Arve 20.12.2013</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Acura UAB                                                                       </td>
            <td>767       </td>
            <td>                              </td>
            <td>          </td>
            <td>Huan Uh 2                                                   </td>
            <td>23445456            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>10 p&#228;eva, viivis 0.5% p&#228;evas                      </td>
            <td>20,00</td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>Acura UAB                                                                       </td>
            <td>                              </td>
            <td>          </td>
            <td>Huan Uh 2                                                   </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>     </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

Tried this but it outputs undefined:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .td-max-height {
      margin: 0px;
      height: 50px;
      max-height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
 </style>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-et.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.contextmenu-fixed2.js"></script>
script src="/Scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(function () {
      $("tr td").wrapInner(function (index, text) {
        return "<div class='td-max-height'>" + text + "</div>";
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
      <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
calculrow            </th>
            <th scope="col">
doktyyp            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokumnr            </th>
            <th scope="col">
fifoexpens            </th>
            <th scope="col">
hind            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klass            </th>
            <th scope="col">
kogpak            </th>
            <th scope="col">
kogus            </th>
            <th scope="col">
koopia            </th>
            <th scope="col">
nimetus            </th>
            <th scope="col">
paritoluri            </th>
            <th scope="col">
prepayment            </th>
            <th scope="col">
toode            </th>
            <th scope="col">
vat            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokarvekonto            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokeimuuda            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokkrdokumnr            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokkuupaev            </th>
            <th scope="col">
dokraha            </th>
            <th scope="col">
doksaaja            </th>
            <th scope="col">
doktasudok            </th>
            <th scope="col">
doktasukuup            </th>
            <th scope="col">
doktekst1            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientaadress            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientnimi            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientotsekorral            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientpiirkond            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientpostiindek            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klienttanav            </th>
            <th scope="col">
klientviitenr            </th>
            <th scope="col">
kreeditdoktasudok            </th>
            <th scope="col">
maksetintingimus            </th>
            <th scope="col">
myygikookmprotsent            </th>
            <th scope="col">
myygikoomaksuvaba            </th>
            <th scope="col">
saajanimi            </th>
            <th scope="col">
saajapiirkond            </th>
            <th scope="col">
saajapostiindek            </th>
            <th scope="col">
saajatanav            </th>
            <th scope="col">
toodekaubakood            </th>
            <th scope="col">
toodeklass            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>135534</td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>197,91000</td>
            <td>T</td>
            <td>0,0000</td>
            <td>0,0000</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>ARLANDA               </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>19.01.2014 0:00:00</td>
            <td>SEK</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>test                       </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use WebGrid, you can specify custom column formatting:

```
gd.Column(
   columnName:"ColumnName", 
   format: (item) => 
   {
      return "<div class='td-max-height'>" + item.Context + "</div>";
   }),
```

With CSS class:

```
.td-max-height {
     margin: 0px;
     height: 50px;
     max-height: 50px;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: auto;
 }
```

If you need help to create the custom column, you can check out this answer for more information:

[how do I create a custom WebGrid Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924964/how-do-i-create-a-custom-webgrid-column)

**Update:**

You can also do it in javascript with JQuery if you want to keep the automatic generation of columns, so to wrap all td elements:

```
$("tr td").each( function() { 
        $(this).wrapInner("<div class='td-max-height'></div>");
    });
```

JS Fiddler link: http://jsfiddle.net/7GHf4/

Comment: Number of columns and column types are not known at design time. Data is created by ado .net datareader from sql select statements generated dynamically at runtime. How to add div s if columns are not known at design time?

Comment: You can do it with JQuery selector to edit specific columns and add the div inside, answer updated.

Comment: thank you. great idea. Column number is not known at design time.  How to add this class='td-max-height' to all td elements in WebGrid?

Comment: It's pretty simple, replace .text with .each, which will iterate all tds. Updated the answer above. You could even count the character in text inside the each function and add the div or not depending on the length of the text.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but row height does not change. alert(text) inside each() call returns `[object HTMLTableCellElement]` . Chrome inpect element shows td elements without any class. How to fix?

Comment: My bad, .wrapInner should be used instead of .text, see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Using wrapInner outputs `undefined` for boolean, integer and character columns instead of column contents. How to allow real column data like without javascript ?

Comment: Please, is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Let me test that and come back to you.

Comment: Do you have example html output of your issue with bool and everything? I cannot reproduce.

Comment: did you reproduced the issue ?

Comment: Yes, but I think you missed one of my edit, you need to use: $(this).wrapInner("<div class='td-max-height'></div>"); and not the old one I posted. You can see the fiddler with the working javascript (I added a yellow background to see the height) at the end of the answer above.

Comment: Dear Karhgath, I have to report that your first solution doesn't work. It only returns the whole div tags as a text. The other solution though saved me a lot of time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

CSS 2.1 rules do not allow you to set maximum height on a table cell or row. To obtain what you want, you need to add the content in a div and set maximum-height and overflow CSS propeties on that div. Here is your modified example (I enclosed in a div element that cell with big content):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

      .withMaximumHeight {
      max-height :50px;
      overflow: hidden;

      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
            calculrow
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            doktyyp
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            dokumnr
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            fifoexpens
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            hind
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            klass
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            kogpak
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            kogus
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            koopia
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            nimetus
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            paritoluri
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            prepayment
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            toode
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            vat
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            dokarvekonto
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            dokeimuuda
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            dokkrdokumnr
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            dokkuupaev
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            dokraha
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            doksaaja
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            doktasudok
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            doktasukuup
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            doktekst1
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            klientaadress
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            klientnimi
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            klientotsekorral
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            klientpiirkond
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            klientpostiindek
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            klienttanav
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            klientviitenr
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            kreeditdoktasudok
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            maksetintingimus
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            myygikookmprotsent
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            myygikoomaksuvaba
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            saajanimi
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            saajapiirkond
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            saajapostiindek
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            saajatanav
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            toodekaubakood
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            toodeklass
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>False</td>
          <td>G</td>
          <td>2045</td>
          <td>False</td>
          <td>362,28813</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>0,0000</td>
          <td>2,0000</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Siduri- ja piduriheebel kinnitustega              </td>
          <td></td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>32-30100            </td>
          <td>1775,61</td>
          <td>112       </td>
          <td>False</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>27.11.2013 0:00:00</td>
          <td>EUR</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>359                      </td>
          <td>7.12.2013 0:00:00</td>
          <td>
            <div class="withMaximumHeight">
              Arve 988 26.01.2012
              Arve  16.08.2012
              Arve 290 16.08.2012
              Muu sissetulnud 24
              Muu sissetulnud 25 2
              Kassa sissetulek 8 4
              Tellimus 43 05.01.2012
              Tellimus 46 24.12.2011
              Arve 292 10.01.2013
              V&#228;ljastus 17.05.2013
              Arve 344 27.09.2013
              Arve 344 27.09.2013
              Arve 05.11.2013
              Tellimus 47 09.08.2013
              Arve 20.12.2013
            </div>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Acura UAB                                                                       </td>
          <td>767       </td>
          <td>                              </td>
          <td>          </td>
          <td>Huan Uh 2                                                   </td>
          <td>23445456            </td>
          <td></td>
          <td>10 p&#228;eva, viivis 0.5% p&#228;evas                      </td>
          <td>20,00</td>
          <td>False</td>
          <td>Acura UAB                                                                       </td>
          <td>                              </td>
          <td>          </td>
          <td>Huan Uh 2                                                   </td>
          <td></td>
          <td>     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>False</td>
          <td>G</td>
          <td>2045</td>
          <td>False</td>
          <td>0,43700</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>0,0000</td>
          <td>0,0000</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Balti v&#252;rtsikilud 270g                            </td>
          <td></td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0075                </td>
          <td>1775,61</td>
          <td>112       </td>
          <td>False</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>27.11.2013 0:00:00</td>
          <td>EUR</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>359                      </td>
          <td>7.12.2013 0:00:00</td>
          <td>
            <div class="withMaximumHeight">
              Arve 988 26.01.2012
              Arve  16.08.2012
              Arve 290 16.08.2012
              Muu sissetulnud 24
              Muu sissetulnud 25 2
              Kassa sissetulek 8 4
              Tellimus 43 05.01.2012
              Tellimus 46 24.12.2011
              Arve 292 10.01.2013
              V&#228;ljastus 17.05.2013
              Arve 344 27.09.2013
              Arve 344 27.09.2013
              Arve 05.11.2013
              Tellimus 47 09.08.2013
              Arve 20.12.2013
            </div>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Acura UAB                                                                       </td>
          <td>767       </td>
          <td>                              </td>
          <td>          </td>
          <td>Huan Uh 2                                                   </td>
          <td>23445456            </td>
          <td></td>
          <td>10 p&#228;eva, viivis 0.5% p&#228;evas                      </td>
          <td>20,00</td>
          <td>False</td>
          <td>Acura UAB                                                                       </td>
          <td>                              </td>
          <td>          </td>
          <td>Huan Uh 2                                                   </td>
          <td></td>
          <td>     </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Table is generated using MVC4 WebGid from dynamic data. How to force WebGrid to generate this div ? I updated question.

Comment: Unfortunately, to configure WebGrid to have a different format for a specific column you will have to set the "columns" element in @gd.GetHtml() method call. Search the web about how to define columns in WebGrid and how to format a column in the WebGrid. The problem is that you might have to define a column element with some default implementation for each of your columns, so there will be more code to write since you have many columns.

Comment: number of columns and column types are not known at runtime, they are returned by ado datareader from runtime created sql. How to force WebGrid to wrap contents with div for every column?

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not be the best option, I think you can get it working by putting the large text inside a `div` before putting it in the table. For example, you could try something like:

```
<td>
<div class="foo"> A very large amount of text here </div>
</td>
```

And then, in your CSS, you could do something like:

```
.foo {
     margin: 0px;
     height: 60px;
     width: 100%;
     min-width: 200px;
     overflow: auto; /* This is if you want the scrollbars. If you want the text to be hidden instead, use 'hidden' */
     }
```

I put together a crude **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Wnf8/)** to give you a basic idea. You should modify the CSS to suit your needs.

Hope that helped `:)`

Comment: thank you. Table in generated by MVC4 WebGrid. How to force webgrid to generate this div? I updated question.

Comment: I am a PHP person, sorry `:(`